# Excel VBA Data validation does change color when numbers are place

Tags: excel, vba, validation

The following code works as expected if I have words besides of numbers etc...

> optionList(0) = "cat"
>
> optionList(1) = "dog"
>
> optionList(2) = "cow"

If I use numbers, the list generates as expected, **but it does not change color.**

I don't get any error announcement. What I am missing here?

```
Public Function addDataValidation(row As Long, column As Long)

Dim optionList(3) As String

optionList(0) = "1"
optionList(1) = "2"
optionList(2) = "3"

    With mySheet.Cells(row, column).Validation

        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
             Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(optionList, ",")

    End With

   With mySheet.Cells(row, column).FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=""1""")
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        .StopIfTrue = False
    End With

    With mySheet.Cells(row, column).FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=""2""")
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        .StopIfTrue = False
    End With

    With mySheet.Cells(row, column).FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=""3""")
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        .StopIfTrue = False
    End With

mySheet.Cells(row, column).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

End Function
```

Comment: Get rid of the extra quotes, you are telling it to look for text that look like numbers not actual numbers: `"=1"`

Comment: Yes. that solved that! :-)